# How much water Earth can hold?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, astrophysics, water, planets

What would happen if we keep adding water to Earth? Earth would become massive, more surface area, and it can hold more water. Finally, would it collapse to a blackhole, or somehow water would be spilled into space?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44872/discussion-on-question-by-vi-su-how-much-water-earth-can-hold).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to gravity, adding water produces heat via a process known as [Kelvin-Helmholtz mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Helmholtz_mechanism).

Once it reaches 65-350 $M_♃$ (Jupiter masses), so the earth bit is already a tiny dot in this huge ellipsoid, the earth doesn't matter now), if there is enough deuterium, it will start fusing deuterium, so it can technically be considered a brown dwarf.

After 350 $M_♃$, the heat produced by gravity should be enough to decompose enough water to the point it is able to sustain fusion and become a brown dwarf

After 1.5 $M_☉$ (solar masses) or 1500 $M_♃$, it will be able to start being a main sequence star.

If more water is added (and where my calculations get fuzzier), it should become a Giant, then a Hypergiant, then it'll collapse to a Neutron Star or Magnetar depending on how the water is added, then it would eventually collapse even more into a black hole.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep adding water endlessly, at some point due to gravitational heat, the the water will be split into hydrogen and oxygen. So much of hydrogen, will make it into a star first. Then depending upon amount of hydrogen and age of the star, it may become a black hole, or a neutron star, or something else. There are many possibilities.